# Get all terms in a custom Wordpress Query?

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

I know how to get all of the Wordpress terms, but I need a "filtered" down version of the results. Is it possible to get all of the terms that are in the result of a Wordpress query? I have this query here:

```
<?php
   $args=array(
  'post_type' => 'gw_activity',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'meta_query' => array(
     'relation' => 'AND',
      array(
         'key' => 'activity_category',
         'value' => 'mindful_life',
         'compare' => '='
      )
   ), 
  'posts_per_page' => 10
);
$my_query = null; 
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) { 
 $all_terms = array();
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>      
  <?php $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $my_query->post->ID, array( 'gw_activity_tag' ) ); ?>
  <?php       
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $all_terms[] = $term->name;
        }        
  ?>                                            
  <?php endwhile; }
  wp_reset_query();
?>
<!-- End Custom Query -->
<?php
    $unique_terms = array_unique( $all_terms ); 
    $result = array_unique($unique_terms);
    foreach ($result as $value) {
        echo $value . '<br />';
    }
```

?>

But I can't figure how to run the query & put a "Where" clause in it, like you can with MySQL. Any help / suggestion or even point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. I'm stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this function: **[wp_get_post_terms()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms)**

Assuming your post supports two taxonomies called `tax_a` and `tax_b`, you can try something like this, exactly where you wrote your comment:

```
<?php $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $query->post->ID, array( 'tax_a', 'tax_b' ) ); ?>

<?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) : ?>
    <p><?php echo $term->taxonomy; ?>: <?php echo $term->name; ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This will print all the terms for each post retrieved by the query.

---

***EDIT***

If what you want is all the terms in all the posts retrieved by the query, you can store the values in an array and then use a function like **[array_unique()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)**, like this:

```
$all_terms = array();
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $all_terms[] = $term->name;
}

// ... and outside the WHILE loop
$result = array_unique( $all_terms );
foreach ( $result as $term ) {
    echo $term . '<br/>;
}
```

Comment: That's working, but unfortunately it's bringing in duplicates terms. Any suggestions?

Comment: That works also, but I'm still getting duplicate terms in the output.

Comment: @TripsLeft, really? Are you printing `$unique_terms`?

Comment: @TripsLeft, firstly you're using `array_unique` twice, do only: `$result = array_unique($all_terms);`. And of course, you should call `array_unique` and print the results **outside** the while loop!

Comment: @TripsLeft, no problem! Note that you're still calling `array_unique` twice, which will work as well, but doesn't make any sense! And remember you can mark the answer as accepted if you're happy with that ;)

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to access the term->slug of the item during the loop so that I can link the term->name to the archive for that term?

Comment: @TripsLeft, yes you can access the slug with `$term->slug`. Look at the docs of the `wp_get_post_terms()` function I linked at the top of my answer, and you will see all the variables of the returned `$term` object...

Comment: For me, this code, `wp_get_post_terms()`, on query results, only shows the terms from the last 1/2 posts.